# Install Lion not mountain lion

Tags: macos

I don't have Mountain Lion and I don't feel like paying 20 bucks for it. I have an older mac using Snow Leopard and I want to install Lion on it. I already bought Lion for a newer mac with my apple account, so I should be able to install Lion on the older one right?

I can't find Lion on the appstore, how do I install Lion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this still works, but give it a shot:

Hold down the Option key when clicking on the Purchased tab key in the Mac App Store app. That shortcut makes Lion reappear in the list (if you bought it there). Make a copy of the installer and put it on a USB key or DVD. You can also Google around to find out how to make a bootable copy as well.